# What is the formula for $\int \cos(\pi x)dx$?

Tags: calculus

I want to evaluate the integral $$\int \cos(\pi x)dx$$

I thought it would simply be $\sin(\pi x) +C$

However in the solutions book the answer is $\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi x)$

This is an integral where it seems as if the chain rule is being performed?

Comment: Do a change of variables: $y = \pi x$.

Comment: $$\int \cos(\pi x)\, dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int \cos (\pi x)\, d(\pi x)$$

$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\sin(\pi x)+C_1\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi x)+C_2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule is reversed in integration. If when you derive you need to multiply, then during integration you need to divide.

Try to derive $\frac{1}{\pi} \sin (\pi x)+C$ to see why this is true.

And generally:

$\int \cos (ax+b)dx=\frac{1}{a}\sin(ax+b)+C$

Comment: Is there a web page with this formula that I may use to memorize?

Comment: Well http://math.stackexchange.com/ ... :)

Comment: Oria, I was thinking of a formula sheet.

Comment: I suggest the OP learns about the general rules rather than memorizing a specific case. For example, this case is the perfect case for the "Inverse Chain Rule Integration", this can be found, among other places of course, here: http://sydney.edu.au/stuserv/documents/maths_learning_centre/chainrulereverse.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the derivative of $\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(\pi x)$
to see that we get the function being integrated.

Remember that $$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))= g'(x)f'(g(x))$$

$g(x)$, here, the inside function, is simply $\pi x$. The outer function, f(x), is the sine function.

$$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(\pi x)=\pi$$
$$f'(g(x))=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\pi}\sin(g(x))=\frac{1}{\pi}\cos(g(x))$$

Multiplying these, and letting $g(x)=\pi x$:

$$(\pi)(\frac{1}{\pi}\cos(\pi x))= \cos (\pi x)$$

Which is what we wanted to show.